# How can I enumerate through a hard coded directory?

Tags: swift, macos, directory, swiftui

I cannot work out why hard coding a directory doesn’t work when trying to enumerate through a directory.

I have written a simple function to open a dialog and return a selected folder. The function includes a starting directory (`directoryURL` below):

```swift
func selectFolder(title: String, directoryURL: String = ".") -> String? {
    let openPanel=NSOpenPanel();
    openPanel.title = title
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    openPanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: directoryURL)
    if(openPanel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
        return directoryURL;        //  This won’t work
        return openPanel.url!.path  //  This is OK
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

In the above function I have prematurely returned with the original directory which is a string, so the whole process is ignored. If I comment out the first `return` statement, then it will return the selected directory, which is *also* a string.

Here is a SwiftUI button to test the function:

```swift
Button(action: {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let sourceFolder = selectFolder(title: "test", directoryURL: "/path/to/folder")
    if let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(
        at: URL(fileURLWithPath: sourceFolder!),
        includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isRegularFileKey],
        options: [.skipsHiddenFiles,.skipsPackageDescendants]
    ) {
        for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
            print("fileURL: \(fileURL)")
        }
    }
}) {
    Text("Test")
}
```

The purpose is to iterate through the contents of the directory, including subdirectories.

If I return the hard coded string from the function, the `for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator` statement has nothing, and there are no results. There are no errors either.

If I return the `openPanel.url!.path`, the `for case …` statement prints the directory contents as expected.

I can’t see what the function returns which is different from the original string.

What can I do to get a hard coded string to work?

Comment: whay dont you just return openPanel.url!

Comment: @Yodagama The question was why using the string by itself doesn’t work. For my application, the `selectFolder` function is called only to change the directory.

Comment: What is `directoryURL: "…/…"` supposed to mean? I suppose it is relative to something but what?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I’ve changed it to `/path/to/folder`.